# Wordpress descending order putting 10 after 1 instead of 2

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have a custom field type called "postorder." I added some php to the template page (see below) to call in the "postorder" for each of the posts, and to sort them in descending order. The problem I am having is that Wordpress is putting 10 after 1. So, the order of my posts is 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. I would like for 10 to come after 9, or find a different value to order my posts.

```
query_posts('showposts=1000&meta_key=postorder&orderby=meta_value&ASC&post_type='.portfolio);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress is treating the values as string to sort, so `10` comes after `1`, just change following

```
orderby=meta_value
```

to (values will be treated as number)

```
orderby=meta_value_num
```

When sorting by number, use `meta_value_num` instead of `meta_value` to make WordPress treat the value as a number instead of a string.